# Fade transition without color?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Is it possible to make a fade transition to another scene without any color? If i use Fade with duration it always gets black for a moment and then shows the next scene, and with crossFade it gets a bit darker and then shows the next scene. But is it possible to just Fade the other scene in so it looks smooth because both my scenes have the same background color and it would look very nice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to resort to some tricks to get the exact effect you want.

- You could fill the start and end scenes with a solid color sprite which fades in and out between presenting the new scene. When presenting a new scene, fade in in the current scene a solid background colored sprite node, present the new scene; the new scene will initially have the solid colored node filling up the entire scene, and will fade out to reveal the scene contents
- Alternate to using sprite nodes, you could experiment with shaders and try to change the transition effect to your liking
- Try to use the `SKTransition.init(ciFilter:duration:)` to create a CI filter that fades to a specific background on the starting scene, and then presents the new scene
- You can render the target scene to a texture, create a sprite node with that texture in the outgoing scene with initial alpha set to 0, fade in that node, and then present the new scen